# SELECT TOP <negative number>

Tags: sql, select

I have encountered a unique problem. Does anybody know if the SELECT TOP command of SQL can take any other parameters as input other than integers. Is there any special case where -1 is used as a parameter for some special functions. (Eg. SELECT TOP -1 from...).

Comment: And what would be the result of that ?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Why are you asking? If it's because you see something pass `-1` to a function or procedure that you know is using the value for a `TOP`, is there a possibility that the `-1` is actually interpreted as `2147483648` in two's complement? `TOP(verylargenumber)` could be used as a shorthand for "get me everything".

Comment: Do you expect "SELECT TOP -1 * ... ORDER BY X DESC" == "SELECT TOP 1 ORDER BY X ASC"?

Comment: Yes. I get an error when I try to select top -1. Just confirming the existence/non-existence of TOP taking -1 as some special input to display something other than the numeric interpretation. 
My question is answered. Thanking you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [`TOP` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) for the syntax of the expression.  You can specify an absolute number of rows or a percentage.  You can include ties, optionally.

It does not allow negative numbers.  Executing:

```
SELECT TOP(-1) *
FROM Table
ORDER BY Id
```

Generates the error: `A TOP N value may not be negative.`

If you want the bottom row, you must modify the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM Table
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

It has some other odd behavior.  You can often omit the parentheses, but you may lose functionality in some cases.  For example, including them means you can specify a parameter, such as:

```
DECLARE @rows INT = 10;

SELECT TOP(@rows) *
FROM Table
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

But this generates a syntax error:

```
DECLARE @rows INT = 10;

SELECT TOP @rows *
FROM Table
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

Finally, remember that `TOP` is non-deterministic (a four letter word in RDBMSs) without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: ..thank you so much..that answers my question perfectly and beautifully.